# One rear wheel hesitates to spin freely after drum brake change

Tags: brakes, vw, polo, parking-brake

I have a Vw Polo 6n2 from 2000 **without ABS**. A while back I replaced rear drum brake cylinders and shoes. After the change, with the wheels *off*, one of the drums were stuck while the other side spin freely (by hand). I had to disengage the *(automatic)* parking brake lever with a screwdriver, but after pulling the hand brake it would get stuck again.

Fast forward many months later, I don't remember exactly what I did back then but now the hand brake lever doesn't get stuck anymore. Yesterday I also adjusted the parking brake cables in the cabin. With the wheels now *on*, [the wheel turns but hesitates to continue](https://i.imgur.com/pJXdY0a.mp4), as if the brakes are slightly engaged.

I've read somewhere that the drum can get a little deformed when hitting it with a small sledgehammer and cause uneven braking, which is possible because IIRC this drum were more stuck compared to the other, so I might have been slightly more violent with this one. Though it's not like there are only certain spots where the wheel hesitates to spin. The hesitation is consistent.

Is this normal? Will this even out eventually? At the moment I'm not able to test drive the car but should I be worried about overheating the brake?

[Here's a video I recorded, comparing the two rear wheels.](https://i.imgur.com/pJXdY0a.mp4)

Also, regarding the adjustment of the parking brake cable. I put the lever on the 4th notch and tightened the left cable until the wheel wouldn't budge. While only adjusting the left cable the right wheel went stiff long before the left wheel, so I loosened the right cable as much as i could to make them somewhat even. This resulted in the left being tightened all the way and the right loosened all the way. [See pictures.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdUa9.jpg) Is this OK? Is this related to the issue explained above?

Comment: Presumably the rear brake's have automatic adjusters.  Do the adjuster seem to be working OK correctly?

Comment: Yes, they are automatic. Yes, I think so. Although, come to think of it, the adjuster might be a little more loose in the connection to the shoe compared to the other side. I remember I could wiggle it perpendicularly inwards, if that makes sense (English is not my native language). I did lubricate the connection very carefully, and while it did not do any difference at the time, I'm thinking the lube might have fully settled in by now since it doesn't get stuck anymore by pulling the hand brake. I'm not sure about adjuster on the other side though. I will go and have a look at it.

Comment: Ok, the play of adjuster on the other side wasn't that much different so I don't think it that has anything to do with it. While I had the drums off I tried pulling the left adjuster on the as much as I could, though it only marginally made the wheel spin easier. I also tried loosen the hand brake cable as much as possible and it made it considerably easier to spin but it wont fully engage the brakes and the hand brake way up (around ten notches). When I disengage, it is not quite as easy to spin the wheel, though only marginally so. Is this a sign that I need to replace the left brake cable?

Comment: Also the automatic adjuster were not in the exact same position as the adjuster on the other side, indicating that the brake cable is slightly more tight. How is this possible? What is causing this? Is it possible that there is rust or some gunk in the guide tube?

Comment: The "adjuster" you're messing with (inside the car at the hand pull) is not what you need to be adjusting. You need to be adjusting the brakes at the wheel itself. [This video](https://youtu.be/8NraBhfWApc) seems pretty comprehensive on how to change and adjust the rear drums (as long as I'm looking at the right model!!!).  I believe you need to release the self adjust wedge to make it stop dragging.

Comment: Are both star wheel adjusters in each wheel brake assembly in their correct position, one marked R for right, the other L for left? (seated driver's reference) One turns clockwise, the other turns counterclockwise when the ratchet lever operated by the parking lever is pulled; each adjuster extends to move the brake shoes towards the brake drum. The parking brake cables should not have to be adjusted in the position you have. Cables don't stretch.  Both parking brake cables should be reset back to original position. Review drum brake operation, star wheel operation and how to adjust them.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Alright! Well, that's actually the video I used to learn how to do the brake job. It's a great video! Very helpful. You're right! I forgot about that one. Months ago I did try to release the self adjusting wedge with a screw driver but it wouldn't budge so pulled on the lever on the brake shoe instead. Come to think of it, I might never had gotten it unstuck. I will inspect it further. Thank you!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I remember carefully thinking of the correct placement of the self adjusting wedge, especially since a couple of months had passed since I did the same thing on the other side. So I _don't think_ I got it wrong, at least the pip is ["away from \[the\] back plate"](https://youtu.be/8NraBhfWApc?t=465). Not sure why it would stick, but I will take a look at it once more and compare it to the other side.

Comment: @FDryer These shoes use an automatic lever (or adjuster, i don't know what you call it :) But yeah, they are in the correct position relative to each side. Good to know about the cables. I'll review! Thank you!

Comment: @FDryer I meant automatic adjuster of course ([self-adjusting wedge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPIPDsawQp8))! Pardon my confusion. :)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Ok so I managed to loosen up the wheel. It now spins freely. Thank you! I readjusted the "adjuster" at the hand pull so each side has about the same amount of tension. However, the right wheel parking brake will engage about two notches sooner than the left wheel. Is this nothing to worry about, and why is it like this?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Also, if I only pull the hand brake like one or two notches from zero, and then fully disengage it again, the self adjusting mechanism doesn't seem to adjust properly and stick a little. I noticed that the wheel hesitated somewhat like before, and only when I properly pulled the hand brake a couple of times it adjusted itself enough to spin freely again. Is this normal?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 To the first question I should add that it seems like adjusting the tension of the cable to the left wheel slightly increases the tension of the cable to the right wheel by itself.

Comment: @neortic Reviewing the video; I've never seen a wedge adjuster and now understand your predicament. As mechanical devices, this may be either relatively easy to balance each side when pulling up the parking brake lever or somewhat complicated. Are your brakes clean and free of rust and severe corrosion? Are there lubrication points needed to reduce binding? A service manual would be valuable for guidance.